# would it be okay to place @keep annotation on domain model in android?

Tags: android, proguard, clean-architecture

I have encountered a problem where my app built for release throws an error with following error logs.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.squareup.moshi.LinkedHashTreeMap cannot be cast to com.myAppPath.domain.model.IconInfo at com.myAppPath.ui.util.BindingAdapterKt.bindImage(BindingAdapter.kt:17) and so on..
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76787979/13892944) and applied it to model in domain layer and it seems working fine.
However, I wonder if it is okay to place `@keep` annotation on model in domain layer since domain layer should not have any dependencies.
Any explanation more than yes/no answer would be appreciated.

my data model looks like this.

```
@Keep
data class IconDTO(
    @Json(name = "url") val iconDtoUrl: String?,
    @Json(name = "width") val width: Int?,
    @Json(name = "height") val height: Int?,
    @Json(name = "format") val format: String?,
    @Json(name = "bytes") val bytes: Int?,
    @Json(name = "error") val error: String?,
    @Json(name = "sha1sum") val sha1sum: String?
)
```

Comment: What is your data model?

Comment: @ΓDΛ updated my post with model in data layer.

Comment: Could you add these rules to your proguard file and try again? https://github.com/square/moshi/blob/master/moshi/src/main/resources/META-INF/proguard/moshi.pro

Comment: I had them already

Comment: The @Keep annotation ensures that an annotated class or method is not removed when the code is minified at build time. This annotation is typically added to methods and classes that are accessed through reflection to prevent the compiler from treating the code as unused.

Comment: right, I got the point. but I am not sure if it is okay to put them in the domain layer though.

Comment: Did you get different results when you added it to the data layer?

Comment: I have had `@keep` on model in data layer and had no issue before even in release build. However, after certain point, I found an error in release build and could solve it as adding `@keep` on model in domain layer. but not sure if putting `@keep` in domain layer is okay.

Comment: In best practices, the data layer is generally used as well. Maybe there may be a deficiency in the mapping process.

Comment: @ΓDΛ, you mean that placing `@keep` only on data layer should be good enough for app to work fine, right?

Comment: Yes because the data models used in datasource types are there.

Comment: This is my idea. I would use it there if I needed it for my personal projects.

Comment: Shouldn't the `@Keep` annotation be used on the definition of the class that is supposed to be kept? The definition lies in the domain layer, so that seems to be the only place to put the `@Keep` annotation but that violates the principles of the domain layer hence the OP question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Keep` annotation is Android specific - it comes from the `androidx.annotation` package and thus doesn't fit in the domain layer as with this import the domain layer would not be reusable in a different (JVM) environment.

You should consider the fact that the domain layer should also be independent of the build process, so that is another reason not to place the `@Keep` annotation inside the domain layer.

My suggestion would be to simply put the class in the `proguard.rules` so that the class and its fields are preserved during the minification:

```
-keep public class your.package.name.IconDTO {*;}
```

If this directive doesn't work I also found the [article](https://medium.com/@dss99911/kotlin-proguard-keep-data-class-ca2660cf2d03) in which there is a more advanced directive:

```
-keepclasseswithmembers class your.package.name.IconDTO {
    public ** component1();
    <fields>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I collected my **comments** as an answer.
—-

The `@Keep` annotation ensures that an annotated class or method is not removed when the code is minified at build time. This annotation is typically added to methods and classes that are accessed through reflection to prevent the compiler from treating the code as unused

In **best practices**, the data layer is generally used as well. Maybe there may be a deficiency in the mapping process

because the `data models` used in `datasource` types are there

This is **my idea**. I would use it there if I needed it for my personal projects.