# App crashes after versions upgrade in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

App crashes after upgrading Gradle, Android Gradle Plugin, JDK versions, compileOptions versions.
Changes are,

```
Gradle: 7.5 -> 8.1  
AGP: 7.4.1 -> 8.1.2  
JDK: 13 -> jbr17  
compileOptions: 1.8 -> 17
```

compileOptions I am referring to

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

After changes above, I see app crashes in release build with following error log.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.squareup.moshi.LinkedHashTreeMap
> cannot be cast to com.myAppPath.domain.model.IconInfo at
> com.myAppPath.ui.util.BindingAdapterKt.bindImage(BindingAdapter.kt:17)
> and so on..

I found [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76787979/13892944) and applied it to corresponding model in **domain** layer and it seems working fine.
However, I doubt if it is okay to place `@keep` annotation on model in domain layer since 1. domain layer should not have any dependencies.  2. I already have had `@keep` annotation on model in data layer so it looks redundant to me.

This is my model in data layer and `@keep` has been there already even before the fix.

```
@Keep
data class IconDTO(
    @Json(name = "url") val iconDtoUrl: String?,
    @Json(name = "width") val width: Int?,
    @Json(name = "height") val height: Int?,
    @Json(name = "format") val format: String?,
    @Json(name = "bytes") val bytes: Int?,
    @Json(name = "error") val error: String?,
    @Json(name = "sha1sum") val sha1sum: String?
)
```

and Here is the place where I think most suspicious place for the error log where instance conversion occurs.

```
@Singleton
class MoshiAdapterConverter @Inject constructor(val moshi: Moshi) {
    inline fun <reified T> convertJsonToObject(json: String?): T? {
        return if (!json.isNullOrEmpty())
            moshi.adapter(T::class.java).fromJson(json)
        else
            null
    }

    inline fun <reified T> convertObjectToJson(objectData: T?): String =
        moshi.adapter(T::class.java).toJson(objectData)

}
```

So my question is,
<s>1. Is it okay to place `@keep` annotation both models in each data layer and domain layer?</s>
2. is there any other solutions other than placing `@keep` on model in domain layer to follow clean architecture principle?

Comment: In the question posted yesterday. Many have been answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77386524/would-it-be-okay-to-place-keep-annotation-on-domain-model-in-android